# Precursor miRNA and a mature miRNA

Tags: genetics, rna, small-rnaseq

What is the main difference between a precursor miRNA and a mature miRNA?

It is often the case that we have more than one precursor miRNA but only one mature miRNA.  The miRNA-seq data contains only precursor miRNAs, so I was wondering if we could use the expression of the precursor miRNA as the expression of the mature product or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

precursor miRNA is ~70mer RNA with a stem loop structure. It is cleaved by dicer to generate one or two mature miRNAs (from one or both the 'arms' of the stem ; called 3p and 5p which are ~22nt long). Refer to [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867404000455) review. (It is an old one and some facts might have changed, but the basics are there.)

Yes, there can be different precursors giving rise to same mature form. There are a few cases like that (check for entries like mir-x-y [where y can be 1,2,3,...], in miRbase).

Usually pre-miRNA is shortlived and is immediately converted to mature form. Therefore, in small RNAseq data, most miRNA reads (more than 90% [at least that's what I get]) come from mature form (pre reads would be longer [after adapter removal] and will contain sequences not retained in mature form). Most algorithms select for the mature reads.

It is difficult to determine which precursor gave rise to a certain mature miRNA, using an RNAseq data. The usual practice is to assign the average read count to each locus. E.g., for a mature form that has 3 precursors, each precursor is assigned 1/3 of the total mature reads. However, in most RNAseq experiments, the objective is to obtain the mature miRNA profile and which precursor gives rise to it becomes immaterial.